# How to set encoding in Intellij searchbox?

Tags: encoding, intellij-idea, search-box

I'd like to know how to set the encoding for Intellij's search box?
The problem is that Chinese characters are correctly shown in editor but in the search window they are shown as squares.

please help

Answer (score 0):

This is typically a system font issue. Take a look at the closed IntelliJ IDEA issue [Malayalam characters are showing as squares in code editor window (and also find window)](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66298). The comments (from the JetBrains developers) provide a solution. Generally, you may need to modify the font specified in *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Appearance > Override default font*.

Comment: unfortunately I can set only 1 font

Comment: when I set a Chinese font, I may not see Latin or Slavic characters
(please note that I search within property files of multiple languages)

Answer (score 0):

Change Look and feel to Nimbus.

File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Appearance > UI Options > Look and feel: > Nimbus

Nimbus excels in text search in internationalization process.
Search within property files of multiple languages for one key and be able to read the value in Latin, Slavic and Asian characters within the 'find pane' respectively 'search box'.